# Verify Latest SSM Agent Installer On Disk

Tags: powershell, amazon-ssm

Sometimes the SSM Agent installer (an exe file), fails to download or becomes corrupted.  Currently, we have the following script that examines the size and downloads if the file is too small on disk.

```
$SizeOfAgentEXE = (Get-Item -Path $PathToAgent).Length
if ($SizeOfAgentEXE -gt 50000000) {
 Do A
} else {
 Do B
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to handle this?  If AWS ever produced a version of this file that was less than 50 MB, the script above would never reach one of the condition blocks.